# Rewriting urls on my website to make it look cleaner

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Ok so i have a website and i want to change this url mywebsite.com/news1.php to mywebsite.com/news.php?id=news1

I am prety sure i need to do this with the Mod_Rewrite in the .htaccess file. But how?

Comment: Is your website currently setup as mywebsite.com/news1.php or mywebsite.com/news.php?id=news1?

Comment: as mywebsite.com/news1.php

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `mywebsite.com/news1.php` as `mywebsite.com/news.php?id=news1`, I suggest:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+).php$ news.php?id=$1
```

Please note, I have not included `Options` or `RewriteEngine On` -- only the rewrite rule. Edit your own code accordingly.

Comment: @user2051894 That means `news.php` does not exist. Have you created/uploaded a file called `news.php`?

Comment: oh derp i didn't it's working thanks :D

Comment: Thanks for your help can i also block the news1 and news2 php files so they can only access it with the news.php?id=news1 format?

Comment: With that rewrite rule in place, the `news1.php` file will never be hit directly. The url will always be rewritten to use `news.php` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just create `.htaccess` file and fill the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$  /news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: That's not the requested url structure.

Comment: @showdev What do you mean?

Comment: OP asked to rewrite `mywebsite.com/news1.php` as `mywebsite.com/news.php?id=news1`. Not `mywebsite.com/news/1/`.

Comment: @showdev will that do the trick? :) I am too noob for this

Comment: @PHP NooB Your answer rewrites `news/3` to `/news.php?id=3`. OP was asking to rewrite `news1.php` as `news.php?id=news1`. See the difference?

Comment: Are you suing XAMPP? WAMP? ...

Comment: showdev is right and im not using a local webhost i bought one online(it's using cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how to do this with .htaccess, but with php code is really simple:

Your `news.php` file:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id){include($id.".php");}
?>
```